# Installed DD-WRT on router, DNS problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, dd-wrt

I recently installed DD-WRT on my TP-LINK wr841n v9 router. The installation seemed to go fine, but the internet doesn't work. I can access the settings page at 92.168.1.1, and in my computer's network settings, it says I am connected to the internet and have an ip address. However, whenever I try to load a page, it gets stuck on the "Resolving host" step. Is there some setting that is missing that's preventing the router from working? Here's some screenshots of the settings pages:

overview:
[image]

setup page:

[image]

--->> Full album here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXfnd.jpg <<---

It seems that people with DNS problems have solved the issue by filling in the static DNS fields, but that didn't work for me. Any idea what could be happening?

**Edit: more info** - the setup is:

ATT U-verse box (not sure if it's a router or not, but it's not wireless) -
inputs: data cable (from the wall), phone line cable, power
outputs: yellow cable (is this the WAN cable?)

Belkin N-Wireless router -
inputs: yellow cable, power
outputs: grey ethernet cable

TP-Link router - 
inputs: yellow cable, power
outputs: (no cables)

What works:
If I connect the Belkin router to the ATT box via the yellow cable, the wireless works. 
If I connect the Belkin router to the ATT box via the yellow cable, then connect the a computer to the router via the grey ethernet cable, the internet works on that computer.
If I connect the TP-link router (before installing dd-wrt) to the ATT box via the yellow cable, the wireless works (with no additional configuration).

What doesn't work:
If I connect the TP-link router (after installing dd-wrt) to the ATT box via the yellow cable, the wireless does not work.

So basically, if I connect another router to the ATT box, things work fine. But for some reason the dd-wrt router doesn't work, even when connected the same way.

Comment: Your internet (WAN) IP is a private IP address, it looks like you are already behind a router which can cause a situation called "double NAT" and some ISP's will block or restrict that traffic. If you plug a computer directly into the WAN cable, can you get internet? Did the router work before flashing DD-WRT? Your usage graph is showing zero incoming or outgoing traffic, so it looks like something is configured is incorrectly, but there isn't sufficient information to determine what it is

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks so much for your reply! See my edits to the question above. The router did function perfectly before flashing dd-wrt. Let me know if there's any additional information necessary to help figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research on "double NAT", I found the following simple fix that worked for me: previously, I had been plugging in the cable that went from ATT modem's LAN/ethernet slot into the TP-Link router's WAN slot. An article suggested leaving the WAN slot alone and instead plugging the cord into the 2nd router's LAN slot. This fixed the issue and the internet works fine now.